# How can I use group_by features of a dataset when creating a bar plot using R and ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to create a function which displays graphs based on `group_by` features of the dataset which should work as the `fill` function. The code does work, but doesn't seem ideal. Can someone please take  a look over it and give some feedback, especially implementing the `.group` argument? Is there maybe a workaround for using `.groups`?

```
 bar_plot <- function(.data, x) {
      ggplot(data = .data, aes({{x}}, fill = as.factor(.group)
      )) +
        geom_bar()+
        labs(colour = group_vars(.data))
    }
    

    mtcars %>%
      group_by(am) %>% bar_plot(cyl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution works fine, the only thing I'd change is

```r
labs(colour = group_vars(.data))
```

as it should be:

```r
labs(fill = group_vars(.data))
```

I think this solution works fine with one variable. If your idea is using two variables then I'd opt for different types of plots.

Comment: thanks. Do you think there is a way i can make the group_by argument of the fill optional? if i there are right now no groups it will give me an error.

Comment: For that, I would rewrite the function so that it doesn't depend on the group_by attribute, specifying .group as an additional argument called grouping (this would also substitute the group_vars(.data)). Then I would use if-else statements so that if `grouping` was NULL then no grouping was used, and otherwise using the standard function. However, I think it would be easier if you just run `ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x)) + geom_bar()` for that